# Runtime error: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: pytorch

I'm currently working on a MAXIM integrated AI project. For more information please check this Github link:
https://github.com/MaximIntegratedAI/ai8x-synthesis
I've been following the steps mentioned in the README file and reached the Model Training and Quantization section.To train the FP32 model for MNIST on MAX78000, I ran the following command:
bash scripts/train_mnist.sh

But I keep getting the error:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Any guidance or hints towards fixing the problem will be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: It means that the PyTorch version you have installed doesn't have support compiled in for your GPU. The PyTorch developers are (in)famous for supporting a limited subset of CUDA hardware in their binary builds and removing features from what they distribute which would allow the CUDA runtime to fix the issue at runtime, all in the name of making the package smaller. People who build add-ons to PyTorch tend to follow that recipe as well

Comment: So I guess I should just follow what Sarthak said and download the latest version of PyTorch? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It depends on what GPU you are using, you have not said

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce 920m (kind of old)

Comment: So, no that won't help. The problem is that PyTorch developers actively exclude many architectures to reduce the package size. They dropped compute 3.5 support from their binaries around PyTorch 1.3 IIRC. You will need to find a source for a version you want with compute 3.5 support compiled in, or you will need to build your own

Comment: @talonmies That's the first I've heard of it!